# Domino custom login page issue

Tags: html, css, https, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying to create custom Login page in `domcfg.nsf`.
Everything works except Style Sheets.
I'm trying to load it from the same Domino server but it seems it cannot load them until I really do log in to the Domino.

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/oneuiv2/base/core.css"
```

Then I was trying to import appropriate css files directly into `domcfg.nsf` and use it as an resource on the form header. But it doesn't work either.
**Note:**

```
     1. In page source I can open .css link and read the content after log in. So path is correct
     2. It doesn't work when I set form property On Web Access Content Type either Notes or HTML
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resources are protected by default. You need to mark your CSS files (design elements) as available for anonymous users.

To do this you need to select the design element in question and mark "Available to Public Access Users." on the security tab.

Comment: that's it.. .Thank you Mr. Lausten

Answer (score 1):

Your domcfg.nsf file ACL also needs to allow Anonymous to have "read public documents" access.